# Vue change style in for Conditionally

Tags: vue.js

I have a v-for and I need to change a style according to the return of a given data.

```
<div id="beerApp">
  <ul>
     <li v-for="cervejaria in cervejarias">   
        <span class="CHANGE Conditionally IF cervejaria.name == 'foo' ">{{cervejaria.name}}</span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

In the angular it is like following:

```
ng-class="cervejaria.name == 'Foo' ? 'task-cat blue lighten-5 black-text' : 'task-cat green'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dynamic class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad) via v-bind to dynamically change the class as following:

```
<li v-for="cervejaria in cervejarias">   
   <span v-bind:class="{'myClass' : cervejaria.name == 'foo'}">         {{cervejaria.name}}</span>
</li>
```

So in above code, `myClass` will be applied only if condition `cervejaria.name == 'foo'` is true.

Comment: For my need to toogle I did the following  [cervejaria.name == 'foo' ? 'blue lighten-5 black-text' : 'green']